# Can I use mutable-content with local push notification instead of remote notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification, push, localnotification

Can I use mutable-content with local push notification instead of remote notification?

For example, send it in userInfo and use Notification Service Extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO.

If you are using the mutable-content and notifications service extension then as per [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) it clearly says:-

> An object that modifies the content of a remote notification before it
>   is delivered to the user.

So you can't use service extension for the purpose of modifying content for local notification before it is delivered to the user.

However, if you are trying to present custom interface you can always use  [content extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension) for local notification.

Hope it clarifies.